# How to implement Code Coverage in a cypress environment where NextJS is build while running the tests?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, cypress, nock

We would like to add code coverage to a setup where we use cypress and nextjs. In our cypress config we build nextJs using next() to mock the backend requests inside nextjs.

The `cypress.config.ts` looks like this:

```js
async setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
  ...
  const app = next({ dev, hostname, port }) // Build application in tests env
  const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

  await app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer(async (req, res) => { // Create server and start application
      ...
      const parsedUrl = parse(req.url!, true)
      await handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
      ...
  }).listen(port, () => {
          console.log(`> Ready on https://${hostname}:${port}`)
  })
})
```

With this setup we can mock tests with nock while testing e2e. Quite similar to this setup: https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/mock-network-from-server/

The problem we are facing now is how to add Code Coverage to this application? We weren't able to instrument the code. Does anybody did this or can link a repo where this is done? Any tipps would help.

Comment: Did you tried this -> https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/code-coverage#E2E-code-coverage ?

Answer (score 1):

So the answer would be it depends. I suggest looking into nextjs swc [discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/30174). Search for coverage and you will find multiple some are hacky ways to do it. This process has 2 steps:

1. **Create Coverage**. I suggest following cypress [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/code-coverage). Ignore babel instructions. setup @cypress/code-coverage. While you test run it should say something about coverage. Image in the docs.
2. **Instrument you code**. Instead of babel I suggest using swc-plugin-coverage-instrument. So the steps would be:

```
yarn add --dev swc-plugin-coverage-instrument

next.config.js
  experimental: {
    swcPlugins: [["swc-plugin-coverage-instrument", {}]],
  },
```

```
// Launch nextjs 
server yarn run dev
// Launch cypress 
npx cypress open
Run Tests
Open Coverage report at coverage/lcov-report/index.html
```

It even works with app-router with some adjustments [here](https://github.com/mike-plummer/nextjs-cypress-ct-example/issues/1)

Here's [examples](https://github.com/mike-plummer/nextjs-cypress-ct-example)

Using Babel. You could probably also simply create .babelrc file, and nextjs will automatically fall back to using babel for transforming individual files. and simply follow cypress code coverage instructions. However nextjs is moving away from babel so this would be a step backwards.